# Compile custom function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to compile a custom function that I created in order to speed up the computation time, which is already small but I am calling the function quite a "few times".

Some dummy data:

```
DD = 20; Days = 4; Peak = 1;
Loading = 
Table[Table[{RandomReal[{-1500, 1500}], 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}/100]}, {i, 1, 150}], {j, 1, Days}];
coo = Loading[[All, All, 1]];
```

The function:

```
Clear[TimeSwapFunctionTEST];  
TimeSwapFunctionTEST[lst_ /; (And @@ (NumericQ /@ lst))] := 
Norm[With[{z = 
 Sort[Partition[
   Flatten[Riffle[Flatten[coo + lst], 
     Flatten[Loading[[1 ;; Days, All, Peak + 1]]]]], 
   2], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]},
Mean[Select[
  Partition[
   Riffle[Mean[Transpose[Partition[z[[All, 1]], DD]]], 
    Abs[Mean[
       Transpose[
        Partition[z[[All, 2]], DD]]]/(StandardDeviation[
         Transpose[Partition[z[[All, 2]], DD]]]/Sqrt[DD])]], 
   2], #1[[1]] > 0 &][[All, 2]]]]]
```

The computation time is around 6" for a thousand shots:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[TimeSwapFunctionTEST[{0, 0, 0, 0}], {i, 1, 1000}]]
{6.0323450, Null}
```

I tried already but I have some problem with the argument `lst_ /; (And @@ (NumericQ /@ lst))` so I have to remove it (but I will need it at the end).
So if I tried this:

```
Clear[TimeSwapFunctionTESTCompiled];
TimeSwapFunctionTESTCompiled = 
Compile[{{lst(*/;(And@@(NumericQ/@lst))*), _Real}}, 
With[{x = 
 Sort[Partition[
   Flatten[Riffle[Flatten[coo + lst], 
     Flatten[Loading[[1 ;; Days, 1 ;; -1, Peak + 1]]]]], 
   2], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]},
Mean[Select[
  Partition[
   Riffle[Mean[Transpose[Partition[x[[All, 1]], DD]]], 
    Abs[Mean[
       Transpose[
        Partition[x[[All, 2]], DD]]]/(StandardDeviation[
         Transpose[Partition[x[[All, 2]], DD]]]/Sqrt[DD])]], 
   2], #1[[1]] > 0 &][[All, 2]]]]]
```

I got these errors:

```
Compile::part: Part specification Compile`FunctionVariable$25889[[All,2]] cannot be     compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the     uncompiled function. >>
Compile::cplist: Compile`$5 should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex;    evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
Compile::cplist: Compile`$5 should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
Compile::cplist: Compile`$6 should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
General::stop: Further output of Compile::cplist will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
Compile::part: Part specification Compile`FunctionVariable$25889[[All,1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
Compile::part: Part specification Compile`FunctionVariable$25889[[All,1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
General::stop: Further output of Compile::part will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

do you have any idea in order to compile this?
Thanks